# How to know that the page is loading? So that I can use my animation controller till the time its loading

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-animation

When clicked on login in button lt should load my custom loader class till the page is loading. How to do that?

Comment: can you show us your minimum verifiable code https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: start loader animation in constructor then await future, When you get result stop loader

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to know when the page is "done loading", you control your login code. These are the steps I usually take in this scenario. These steps describe what I do from when firing the onTap function in the button.

1. Show a busy indication dialog using showDialog
2. Perform the login using a future
3. Add a .then method to the future and .catchError
4. When either of those callbacks fire then I call Navigator.of(context).pop() to remove the dialog
5. Perform your navigation to the new view on success.

Answer (score 0):

Use [FutureBuilder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) widget. `ConnectionState.waiting` can be used to show loading animations.